# Nginx regex in location path or server_name

Tags: regex, nginx

I am trying to use regex with nginx to allow requests containing some conditions without success.

for example one of the errors `ginx: [emerg] pcre_compile() failed: missing ) in "(^/(unsafe)\/([0-9]" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/file.conf:33`.

The regex should be ok according to `https://regex101.com/`, so I guess the issue with the nginx and this regex, so I need some help how to do it.

Regex:

```
^(http|https):\/\/(my[.]domain[.]com)\/(unsafe)\/([0-9]{0,4})x([0-9]{0,4})\/((ch)|[a-z0-9]{0,32})\/(([3_]+[a-z0-9]{0,32}\.jpg)|([c_1_]+[a-z0-9]{0,32}\.jpg)|([a-z0-9]{0,32}\.jpg)|(fb\/[0-9]{0,6}.jpg)|([a-z0-9]{0,6}\/[0-9]{0,6}.jpg))
```

Urls:

```
https://my.domain.com/unsafe/1530x55/7550/3_c892b2c2de030f40.jpg
https://my.domain.com/unsafe/1030x1345/71b0c5d3f50/c_1_c8928dc3e030f40.jpg
https://my.domain.com/unsafe/1030x4443/79481b0c5d3f50/c892333e030f40.jpg
https://my.domain.com/unsafe/0x0/ch/fb/157233.jpg
https://my.domain.com/unsafe/0x0/ch/6chars/123456.jpg
```

1.

`server_name ~^(my[.]domain[.]com)\/(unsafe)\/([0-9]{0,4})x([0-9]{0,4})\/((ch)|[a-z0-9]{0,32})\/(([3_]+[a-z0-9]{0,32}\.jpg)|([c_1_]+[a-z0-9]{0,32}\.jpg)|([a-z0-9]{0,32}\.jpg)|(fb\/[0-9]{0,6}.jpg)|([a-z0-9]{0,6}\/[0-9]{0,6}.jpg));`

or:

`location ~ (/(unsafe)\/([0-9]{0,4})x([0-9]{0,4})\/((ch)|[a-z0-9]{0,32})\/(([3_]+[a-z0-9]{0,32}\.jpg)|([c_1_]+[a-z0-9]{0,32}\.jpg)|([a-z0-9]{0,32}\.jpg)|(fb\/[0-9]{0,6}.jpg)|([a-z0-9]{0,6}\/[0-9]{0,6}.jpg))) { 
     empty
}`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have braces in your regular expression, `nginx` requires it to be quoted. It's mentioned for [the rewrite directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite), but I think it's applicable for most `nginx` directives that accept a regular expression.

Comment: you right on the location path, but somehow when I do it on the `server_name`, i got an error `nginx: [emerg] directive "server_name" is not terminated by ";"`, but I have the `;`, any thoughts?

Comment: The `server_name` regular expression needs to be quoted if it contains braces. The `server_name` expression in your question is invalid anyway, as it is not a server name.

Comment: seems like no need to escape forward-slashes in nginx location. thanks for your help.

Comment: Correct. But you have some `.`s in your question that should be escaped. Also, not sure what `[c_1_]` means.

Comment: I figured it out how to do it with nginx, somethings needed to be change, not everything that work in `https://regex101.com/` also work in nginx.